# Is it safe to call vector.resize(0) after moving its content

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In other words is the following code  sound(defined behavior,portable,...)

```
   std::vector<int> vec(100,42);
   std::vector<int> other = std::move(vec);
   vec.resize(0);//is this sound

   //using vec like an empty vector
```

Comment: You can do *anything* with that `vector` that does not expect any particular properties (beyond validity). I'd prefer `clear()` over `resize(0)`, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

From §23.3.6.5:

> If `sz <= size()`, equivalent to calling `pop_back()` `size() - sz` times. If `size() < sz`, appends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.

So basically, when you call `resize(0)`, it calls `pop_back()` until every element is removed from the vector.

It doesn't matter that you moved `vec`, because even though the state of `vec` is unspecified, it is still a valid vector that you can modify.

So, the `std::vector` will be empty after a call to `resize(0)`.

Comment: No, you can't call `pop_back()`, because `pop_back()` has preconditions. However, `size()` does not, and once you've called `size()`, and ensured it is greater than 0, you've checked that the vector satisfies the preconditions of `pop_back()`, and so it is then safe to call it.

Comment: [FYI] It is a [defect](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2160) to define `resize` in terms of `pop_back`.

Answer (score 5):

After having moved from an object, you can generally not make any assumptions about the object's state. That means that you can only call member functions that do not have any preconditions. Happily, `std::vector::resize` does not have value-dependent preconditions, so you can call `resize` on a moved-from vector.

Comment: *you can generally not make any assumptions about the object's state* **wrong**: you can assume it's valid. That's the whole point.

Comment: As for the preconditions mentioned for resize. §23.3.6.3 : 13 *Requires: T shall be MoveInsertable and DefaultInsertable into *this.*

Comment: @Walter: That goes without saying. Every object is valid. Otherwise it's not an object.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Yes. That's not value-dependent; that depends only on the *type*. So it doesn't relate to whether you've moved from a container.

Comment: @KerrekSB I should have been explicit about the conclusion. Your comment clarifies the intent of mine, thanks

Comment: @KerrekSB that is flat-out wrong, if the move garbled the vector's members instead of marking it as empty (or whatever), it would not be in a valid state. moving objects must leave the moved object in a valid state.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: Such an object would not be destructible, and the destructor, too, has no value-dependent preconditions.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, this was exactly the point of the question: is the object in a valid state (such that `resize(0)` can be called)? And, of course, it has to be. Since 'valid state' and 'destructible' are two different things, this was apparently not obvious to the user. *Otherwise it's not an object* -- nonsense: an object can be in an invalid state (put there by buggy code, e.g. via a race condition).

Comment: @Walter: I get your point, of course, and I know about the much quoted "valid but unspecified". But I'd like to make a point that the move construction and assignment are just normal member functions, and they aren't special in any way that diverges from existing conventions and design, and there is nothing that needs to be explicitly called out. The takeaway is that "unspecified state" means "may not satisfy any preconditions".